# Delete button not functioning

Tags: php, mysqli

I created a that submits straight into A database example with a table in the database named validation. After the form it's been submitted I retrieve the data submitted from the database. I had no problems with the retrieving of data from the Database to a page I created and named it Receive.php. I created a *Do While Loop* , so that every row of data will have a delete Button and an Edit button. The problem am facing is my delete button don't seem to be functioning and I also want to use PhP only in making it work thus no JavaScript or jquery etc would or should be used. My code is as follows :

```
<?php 
Include sql.php //connecting to Database
$query = "SELECT * FROM validation";
mysqli_query ($con , $query);
$result = mysqli_query ($con , $query);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result);
$totals = mysqli_num_rows ($result);

?>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['remove'])){
$id = $_POST['id'];
Include 'Sql.php';
$query1 = "DELETE FROM Validation  WHERE ID = '$id' LIMIT 1";
$results = mysqli_query ($con , $query);
}
?>
<?php 
$i = "";
 do{$i=$i+1; ?>
<tr> 
   <td><?php echo $i; ?>.</td>

   <td><?php echo $rows ['Name']; ?>.</td>
    <td><?php echo $rows ['Email']; ?>.</td>
    <td><?php echo $rows ['Website']; ?>.</td>
   <td><?php echo $rows ['Comment']; ?>.</td> 
    <td><?php echo $rows ['Time']; ?>.</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="remove" value"Delete"/>
<?php } while ( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) ?>
```

**I also created a hidden input type that will submit or post an Id into the database which corresponds with that of the database.. 
Any help will be of much importance. 
Am posting the full code it contains to pages one is the ***index.php*** which is where the main form is and the other is ***receive.php*** thus after submitting to the database this page is where the data would be retrieve from the database for the end user.**

*INDEX.PHP*

```
<?php  



if (isset($_POST["submit"])){ 
 $id = $_POST['id']; 
$name = $_POST["name"]; 
$email = $_POST["email"];
$website = $_POST["website"];
$comment = $_POST["comment"];
$gender = $_POST["gender"];


  $con = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "rupert", "" , "example") or die ("Database connect error");
  mysqli_select_db($con, "example") or die ("error connecting to database");



     if (!empty($_POST["name"])){
         $query = "INSERT INTO validation (ID,Name, Email, Website, Comment)
                   VALUES(NULL,'$name' , '$email' , '$website'  , '$comment')";
                   mysqli_query($con, $query) ;
     } else{
         echo " error inserting data";
     }


}
$namErr = $emailErr = $websiteErr = $commentErr = $genderErr ="";
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] =="POST") {
    if(empty($_POST["name"])){
    $namErr = "Name is Required";
    }else{
        $name = test_input( $_POST["name"]); 
    }
    if(empty($_POST["email"])){
    $emailErr = "Email is Required";
    }else{
         $email = test_input($_POST["email"]); 
    }
    if(empty($_POST["website"])){
    $websiteErr = "Website is Required";
    }else{
         $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
    }
    if(empty($_POST["comment"])){
    $commentErr = "Comment is Required";
    }else{
        $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
    }
    if(empty($_POST["gender"])){
    $genderErr = "Gender is Required";
    }else{
       $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]); 
    }
}
    function test_input($data) {

    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data); 
    return $data;
    }  


    ?>

 <div id="contain">   
<form  method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" > 
        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" />
 NAME : <input type="text" name="name" id="name"> 
 <span class="error">* <?php echo $namErr ;?></span>
 <br><br> 
 EMAIL : <input type="text" name="email" id="email" >
 <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr ;?></span>
 <br><br>
 WEBSITE : <input type="text" name="website" id="website"> 
 <span class="error"> <?php echo $websiteErr ;?></span>
 <br><br>
 COMMENT : <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea> 
 <span class="error"> <?php echo $websiteErr ;?></span> 
 <br><br> 
 GENDER : 
    <select name="gender" id="gender"> 
    <option selected>Please Select</option> 
    <option value="M">Male</option>
    <option value="F">Female</option>
    </select>

 <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr ;?></span>
 <br><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /> 
 <input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset" />

</form>


</div>
```

*RECEIVE.PHP*

```
<?php 

     include 'sql.php'; 
     $query = "SELECT * FROM validation";
    mysqli_query($con , $query);
  $result = mysqli_query($con , $query);
  $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
  $tottals = mysqli_num_rows($result);



     if (isset($_POST['del'])){ 

        $id = $rows ['ID'];
        $query1 = "DELETE FROM validation WHERE ID = '$id' "; 
        $results = mysqli_query($con , $query1); 
        }
       ?>





 <div id="css">
<form >
 <table width="80%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" > 
  <caption><h2>Personal Details of Customers</h2></caption> 
  <tr class="white"> 
   <td bgcolor="#330033">&nbsp;  </td> 
   <td bgcolor="#330033"> Full Name </td>
   <td bgcolor="#330033"> Email Address </td>
   <td bgcolor="#330033"> Website </td>
   <td bgcolor="#330033"> Comment </td> 
   <td bgcolor="#330033"> Time </td>   


   </tr>


  <?php 
  $i=""; 
   do{$i=$i+1;?>

    <tr> 
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><?php echo $i;?>.</td> 
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><?php echo $rows ['Name']; ?></td> 
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><?php echo $rows ['Email'];?></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><?php echo $rows ['Website'];?></td> 
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><?php echo $rows ['Comment'];?></td> 
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><?php echo $rows ['Time'];?></td>  

     <td>&nbsp; </td>
     <td> <input type="submit" name="del" value="Delete" /> &nbsp; <input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit"  /> </td>
    </tr>

   <?php }while ($rows= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) ?>  









 </table>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags.  [tag:phpmyadmin] has nothing to do with anything in your question.

Comment: For one thing, you're using `mysqli_query` twice. Plus, where are your form tags?

Comment: Other than that there's nothing wrong with my query ??

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume that you have posted part of the code as you have no `table` or `form` tags around your submit input tag.

Presuming you do have a form tag, check that you've actually set your `form action` attribute to `get`.  It would be an EXTREMELY bad thing to actually be meaning to send your submit data by a `GET` header.

If you've forgotton to put your `form` tags in, then that'll be why.

Update:

You are trying to extract from the `GET` super global which won't exist.

```
if(isset($_POST['remove']))
```

**UPDATED ANSWER BASED ON WHOLE FILE**

ok, a few things (Ive added comments in the code with the bullet point number to help you see where you went wrong)

1. As you already ran the query to get the records from the database at the top of the page, you dont need $i++ in your loop. You can just rely on `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to do the work for you.
2. You were not actually sending any data via your form to the php script other than your login button.  What Ive done here is just use a radio button which can be selected to inform your script of which record you are talking about.  Because its using the actual `id` of the database table itll be accurate.
3. Ive sanitized the $_POST data going into the query.  There are far better ways of doing this, but it'll do in the scope of what your doing for now.
4. Ive also tidied up your code.  Make sure you always indent properly AS YOU WORK.  Itll make it far easier to debug. Learning how to do this is a priority.
5. Ive also used 'magic quotes' eg. " to echo the table out.  This way you can refer to the variable names without having to stop.start your html.  It just echo's out the whole lot and inserts variable names where needed.

Ive not tested this, so I might have a typo that I cant see. Its late and Ive been staring at the PC for 10 hours today but it looks close.

**THE CODE**

`````
<?php 

include 'sql.php'; 
$query = "SELECT * FROM validation";
mysqli_query($con , $query);
$result = mysqli_query($con , $query);
$tottals = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if (isset($_POST['del'])){ 
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['ID']);  // COMMENT number 2 ( I know theyre out of order but it was easier to explain this way around )
    $query1 = "DELETE FROM validation WHERE ID = '$id' "; 
    $results = mysqli_query($con , $query1); 
}
?>

<div id="css">
    <form >
        <table width="80%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" > 
            <caption><h2>Personal Details of Customers</h2></caption> 
            <tr class="white"> 
                <td bgcolor="#330033">&nbsp;  </td> 
                <td bgcolor="#330033"> Full Name </td>
                <td bgcolor="#330033"> Email Address </td>
                <td bgcolor="#330033"> Website </td>
                <td bgcolor="#330033"> Comment </td> 
                <td bgcolor="#330033"> Time </td>   
            </tr>
            <?php 
            while ($rows= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) // COMMENT number 1
            {
                // COMMENT 5 - start of insert table row
                echo "
                <tr> 
                    <td bgcolor='#FFFFCC'><input type='radio' name='ID' value='$rows[ID]'/></td>   <!-- COMMENT number 3 -->
                    <td bgcolor='#FFFFCC'>$rows[ID]</td> 
                    <td bgcolor='#FFFFCC'>$rows[Name]</td> 
                    <td bgcolor='#FFFFCC'>$rows[Email]</td>
                    <td bgcolor='#FFFFCC'>$rows[Website]</td> 
                    <td bgcolor='#FFFFCC'>$rows[Comment]</td> 
                    <td bgcolor='#FFFFCC'>$rows[Time]</td>  
                    <td>&nbsp; </td>
                    <td> <input type='submit' name='del' value='Delete' /> &nbsp; <input type='button' name='edit' value='Edit'  /> </td>
                </tr>
````            "; // end of insert table row
            }?>  
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
`````

Comment: have you tried it out yet because am having syntax errors in all the lines pertaining to the loop

Comment: Keep on getting this notice :    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'bgcolor' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ak\receive.php on line 60

Comment: if youve copied that file, there is no line 60

Comment: I copied it and its now Line 42 thus the next two rows after echo"

Comment: oh I see why. I left the "" in the $row[] calls

Comment: am confused right now an illustration would be okk pllss!!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65170/discussion-on-answer-by-matt-holbrook-bull-delete-button-not-functioning).

Comment: All is well but the rows are just not deleting..This is what i get in my address bar http://localhost/ak/receive.php?ID=8&del=Delete#